# Redux fields rendering showing issue: Cannot read property 'length' of null at deleteInWithCleanUp (deleteInWithCleanUp.js:19)

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

My form already get loaded at first time. Again on a button click, I am rerendering my form on the basis of condition is that case it is showing me an error like that:

[image]

It also showing me one more error just below this error : -

[image]

Comment: Can you post code snippets of your react and redux? This way the problem can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

The form's state subtree is destroyed when the form is unmounted, by design. This is the default and expected behaviour.

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

reduxForm({
  form: 'example',
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(...)
```